# FWTools/GDAL error in release version

Tags: c#, exception, gis, access-violation, gdal

I'm using FWTools and SharpMap (with gdal_sharp) to build an application. And I have a weird error. Loading a raster layer runs great in Debug mode, but in Release it throws an Exception in SharpMap.Layers.GdalRasterLayer in the constructor when calling

```
 _projectionWkt = _gdalDataset.GetProjectionRef();
```

The full exception is:

```
{System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE.Dataset_GetProjectionRef(HandleRef jarg1)
   at OSGeo.GDAL.Dataset.GetProjectionRef()
   at SharpMap.Layers.GdalRasterLayer..ctor(String strLayerName, String imageFilename) in d:\Fakultet\IX Semestar\GIS\Projekat\GreenGIS\SharpMap.Extensions\Layers\GdalRasterLayer.cs:line 404
   at GreenGIS.Form1.addRasterLayer() in d:\Fakultet\IX Semestar\GIS\Projekat\GreenGIS\GreenGIS\Form1.cs:line 50
   at GreenGIS.Form1.toolStripButtonAddVector_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Fakultet\IX Semestar\GIS\Projekat\GreenGIS\GreenGIS\Form1.cs:line 129
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at GreenGIS.Program.Main() in d:\Fakultet\IX Semestar\GIS\Projekat\GreenGIS\GreenGIS\Program.cs:line 19}
```

The weird thing is that in Debug everything works fine. The build setup is exact, both .Net 4.0, x86 Platform.

Any ideas?

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Do the run-times in all of the C++ projects match each other when in Release configuration?

Comment: Yes they do match. Checked that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with Windows 8 and it's DEP implementation along with .Net 4.0. I'm using a C++ dll in a wrapper, and the OS does not let it execute. It could be solved by editing the DLL or turning Data Execution Prevention off.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problems but after using the current compiled binaries from [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php) the problem was fixed. I documented the steps that worked for me at http://vipassanaandenvironmentalinformatics.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/getting-started-with-c-and-gdal.html.

Hope this answer is still of help to others.